# JavaScript ES6 - console.log with template literal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I'm writing node's script that connect to the mongo database.

I noticed that printing error response is different by small change in `console.log` syntax. Below example should be more meaningful.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const config = require("./config");

mongoose.connect(config.dbURI, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(`${err}`); // First console.log
        console.log(err); // Second console.log
    } else {
        console.log(`Database connection successful`)
    }
});
```

Example output of the first `console.log`

```
MongoError: Authentication failed.
```

Example output of the second `console.log`

```
{ MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at Function.MongoError.create (/Users/sigo/Sources/crypto-change/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at /Users/sigo/Sources/crypto-change/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:489:72
    at authenticateStragglers (/Users/sigo/Sources/crypto-change/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:435:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (/Users/sigo/Sources/crypto-change/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/sigo/Sources/crypto-change/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:321:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:563:20)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'Authentication failed.',
  ok: 0,
  code: 18,
  errmsg: 'Authentication failed.' }
```

Where comes from this difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${err}` (or `'' + err` for that matter) will interpolate the `err` object with a string which will also change your [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) object into a string  - which is equivalent to calling [err.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/toString). However directly logging `err` will pass it to the console as an object and display it in that manner.

This is called "implicit coercion" - if you would like to know more about this subject I can highly recommend reading [You Don't Know JS: Types & Grammar (Chapter 4: Coercion)](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md#chapter-4-coercion) for a deep dive.

Comment: Whoa. This is clever. Thanks for the links! I even now know how JavaScript choose values pull from the object.

Answer (score 2):

By interpolating in a template string, the [`err` object](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/core/api/MongoError.html) is cast to a string, using its own `.toString` method that is [inherited](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/core/api/lib_error.js.html#line42) from [`Error.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/toString). The code is equivalent to

```
console.log(String(err));
console.log(err.toString());
```

When passing the `err` object directly to the [`console.log` method](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args), it uses [node's `inspect` function](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) instead, the code is equivalent to

```
console.log(util.inspect(err));
```